# Find and replace notepad++ with numbers and wildcard

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, I want to find "," and replace with " "

Example:

```
"arcs,": "properties,": "FIPS": 1234,
"arcs,": "properties,": "FIPS": 56789,
"arcs,": "properties,": "FIPS": 45785631,
```

To be replaced as

```
"arcs,": "properties,": "FIPS": 1234
"arcs,": "properties,": "FIPS": 56789
"arcs,": "properties,": "FIPS": 45785631
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The OP's original need is actually based on:

> {"arcs": [[-12172, 13480]], "type": "Polygon", "properties": { "FIPS":
>   1745, } }, { "arcs": [[13481, -12967]], "type": "Polygon",
>   "properties": { "FIPS": 56789, } }

A normal search/replace can be used for that:

[image]

In the Find what box, input: <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>

In the Replace with box, input: <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Paul for your quick response, for easy understanding, I copy pasted part of my code, but when I tried to deploy your idea, it is not working

Comment: {"arcs": [[-12172,
 13480]],
 "type": "Polygon",
 "properties": {
 "FIPS": 1745,
 }
 },
 {
 "arcs": [[13481,
 -12967]],
 "type": "Polygon",
 "properties": {
 "FIPS": 56789,
 }
 }
In the above code, I want to remove the "," from  "FIPS": 1745, and "FIPS": 56789,

Comment: Switch back to `Normal` search mode.  In the `Find what` box, input: `, }` (there a space in the middle) ... then in the `Replace with` box, input:  `}` (a space followed by } )

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the actual criteria.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you once again, the file has "FIPS": 1745, and in the next line }, so when I search, it is not coming up. Is there anyway, I can attach the file and send it to you for easy undestanding? Thank you!

Comment: I copy/pasted what you provided a few comments ago. Is the `wrap around` box checked too? The line where that it is located should not matter. (unless you mean in the search fields??) Also ensure that the `In selection` checkbox is NOT checked too.

Comment: Great! ... glad it worked. Please accept the answer when you get a chance.